# Did Will Durant say "The Islamic conquest of India is probably the bloodiest story in history"?

Tags: quotes

[DanielPipes.org](http://www.danielpipes.org/comments/32812) claims Will Durant said:

> "The Islamic conquest of India is probably the bloodiest story in history. It is a discouraging tale, for its evident moral is that civilization is a precious good, whose delicate complex of order and freedom, culture and peace, can at any moment be overthrown by barbarians invading from without or multiplying within."

The same claim was quoted in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9626/is-there-anything-against-islam-in-hindu-texts) Hinduism.SE answer. It says:

> Will Durant, the famous historian summed it up like this:
>
> "The Islamic conquest of India is probably the bloodiest story in
>   history. It is a discouraging tale, for its evident moral is that
>   civilization is a precious good, whose delicate complex of order and
>   freedom, culture and peace, can at any moment be overthrown by
>   barbarians invading from without or multiplying within."

Did he say this? And did he call the conquests "Islamic"?

Comment: "There is no official estimate of the total death toll of Hindus at the hands of Islam. Prof. K.S. Lal once estimated that the Indian population declined by 50 million under the Sultanate, but that would be hard to substantiate; research into the magnitude of the damage Islam did to India is yet to start in right earnest." You can read the more actual numbers under the section "Hinduism's losses" here-http://koenraadelst.bharatvani.org/articles/irin/genocide.html

Comment: Research effort?  The second Google hit for "will durant islamic conquest" gives the book's title, volume and chapter number.

Comment: @NateEldredge But that is not Durant's original wording in his original book.  Did the publisher change the wording at some point? and if so was it with or without Durant's input? There are at least 6 wording changes from the original in that short quote.  Is the book misquoted or was the book changed in later editions? Did Durant author the wording changes (if there were any)?

Comment: @DavePhd-Koenraad Elst quotes the same but replaces the word 'Mohammedan' with 'Islamic' in his article 'Was There an Islamic "Genocide" of Hindus?' present here-http://koenraadelst.bharatvani.org/articles/irin/genocide.html.

Comment: @pericles316 Yes, I discuss Elst in my answer, but changing  "Mohammedan" to "Islamic" is just one of about 6 changes in Elst's quotation.

Comment: Related question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/did-indias-population-decrease-by-80-million-between-1000-and-1525-ce

Comment: Yes, Will Durant did say it. Maybe a few words were changed to synonyms to make it sound more natural, but irrespective of the version, the meaning remains unchanged. The "evident moral" Will Durant wanted to convey is not altered in any way by the version of the quote present in the 1972 edition of his book.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He wrote in [The story of civilization, Part 1: Our Oriental Heritage](https://books.google.com/books?id=ER1mAAAAMAAJ&q=%22will%20durant%22%20%22The%20Mohammedan%20Conquest%20of%20India%20is%20probably%20the%20bloodiest%20story%20in%20history%22&dq=%22will%20durant%22%20%22The%20Mohammedan%20Conquest%20of%20India%20is%20probably%20the%20bloodiest%20story%20in%20history%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj81rzfq9PQAhXIPiYKHRYLBH8Q6AEISTAI) at page 459 ([alternative link](https://archive.org/details/storyofcivilizat035369mbp)):

> The Mohammedan Conquest of India is probably the bloodiest story in history. It is a discouraging tale, for its evident moral is that civilization is a precarious thing, whose delicate complex of order and liberty, culture and peace may at any time be overthrown by barbarians invading from without or multiplying within.

So he said "Mohammedan", not "Islamic"; "precarious thing", not "precious good"; "liberty", not "freedom"; "may", not "can" and "time", not "moment".

Also, the statement is under a heading "THE MOSLEM CONQUEST".

Keep in mind that this was originally written in 1935, so it does not include World War Two when he says this.

The version of the quote in the OP is as Will Durant is quoted by Koenraad Elst in the 1992 book [Negationism in India: Concealing the Record of Islam](https://books.google.com/books?id=mBEcAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22islamic%20conquest%22):

> Will Durant summed it up like this "The Islamic conquest..."

The book [Contemporary views on Indian civilization](https://books.google.com/books?id=h_9tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Islamic%20conquest%20of%20India%20is%20probably%20the%20bloodiest%22&dq=%22Islamic%20conquest%20of%20India%20is%20probably%20the%20bloodiest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY6tHXvdXQAhVEOiYKHfbkBTE4FBDoAQgZMAA) says:

> To quote Will Durant's famous line (1972:459): "The Islamic conquest..."

So it is saying that a 1972 edition of Durant's book has the OP quote, but, even if that is true, that is not the original version that Durant wrote.

A [recent publication of Durant's book which Google Books says is from 2011](https://books.google.com/books?id=ru4LPyMAxxkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22our%20oriental%20heritage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_vaavxdXQAhUKwiYKHb7oC1EQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22mohammedan%20conquest%22&f=false) by the original publisher Simon and Schuster still has the original version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49467/discussion-between-pericles316-and-mohammad-sakib-arifin).

Comment: All further discussion about which side of the fighting was "right" should be taken to chat. I've deleted such comments here.

Comment: I must commend the amount of time and effort you dedicated to comparing the versions and highlighting the differences. Thanks for writing the answer.

Comment: Ha ha, who do you think mohammadans are? What's their ideology?

Answer (score 8):

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Y8j.jpg) is from the 1952 edition of *The Story of Civilization, Part 1: Our Oriental Heritage* by Will Durant. It’s volume one, page 459.

[image]

OCR conversion below:

> VI. THE MOSLEM CONQUEST
>
> The weakening of India—Mahmud of Ghazni—The Sultanate of Delhi—Its cultural asides—Its brutal policy—The lessson of Indian history
>
> The Mohammedan Conquest of India is probably the bloodiest story in history. It is a discouraging tale, for its evident moral is that civilization is a precarious thing, whose delicate complex of order and liberty, culture and peace may at any time be overthrown by barbarians invading from without or multiplying within. The Hindus had allowed their strength to be wasted in internal division and war; they had adopted religions like Buddhism and Jainism, which unnerved them for the tasks of life; they had failed to organize their forces for the protection of their frontiers and their capitals, their wealth and their freedom, from the hordes of Scythians, Huns, Afghans and Turks hovering about India's boundaries and waiting for national weakness to let them in. For four hundred years (600—1,000 A.D.) India invited conquest; and at last it came.
>
> The first Moslem attack was a passing raid upon Multan, in the western Punjab (664 A.D.) Similar raids occurred at the convenience of the invaders during the next three centuries, with the result that the Moslems