# Have about 170 million people been killed in the name of Allah?

Tags: history, criminology, mortality, islam, statistics

In a question recently asked on the Christianity site, namely, [Why don’t Christians accept Muhammad as the true prophet?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89037/50422), an [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89040/50422) quoted [this article](https://www.crisismagazine.com/2016/was-muhammad-a-false-prophet):

> “Beware of false prophets who … inwardly are ravenous wolves.” “Ravenous” certainly seems an apt description of Muhammad. While it’s not know exactly how many people he killed in the course of spreading Islam, it is known that on one occasion he presided over the beheading of between 600 and 900 captured men. “Ravenous” also seems to fit most of his successors. Islam’s’ 1400 year history is largely a record of conquest and subjugation. By one estimate, **approximately 170 million people have been killed in the name of Allah, making Islam the greatest killing force in history by far**.

The article references the book [A Self Study Course on Political Islam-Level 1-CD, levels 2 & 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N63VMDC) as its source, which is in paperback and, unfortunately, behind a paywall.

Have about 170 million people been killed in the name of Allah?

Comment: I’m wondering what “killed in the name of Allah” is supposed to mean, a Muslim killing someone, all deaths in a religious war, deaths in a war by a party/individuals that are Muslim, deaths caused by Muslims specifically saying it is in the name of Allah, there are practically infinite ways that someone could interpret that statement as.

Comment: @Topcode - I haven't read the referenced book (see my excuse in the OP), but I would suppose (I could be wrong) that the author only counted murders performed in the context of [offensive Jihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jihad#Defensive_and_offensive_jihad).

Comment: I think this question could be answered in two parts: firstly, is there any reasonable basis for the "170 million people killed" in the quote; and second, as Tim Harford likes to ask on BBC More or Less, "is this a big number?" That is, if we applied a similar methodology to other "causes" of death, would the statistic look meaningless - after all, the WHO [attributes 8.9 million deaths *in a single year* to "ischaemic heart disease"](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/the-top-10-causes-of-death).

Comment: Just to complicate things further, my understanding is that Christians, Jews, and Muslims all worship the same deity. Muslims call Him "Allah", Christians call Him "God", and Jews call Him "Yahweh", but He is the same deity in all three religions. So would killing in the name of the Christian God count as killing in the name in Allah?

Comment: @F1Krazy Well, pedantically, you could argue that "in the _name_ of" can't refer to a different _name_. I think it's pretty clear from context, though, that the actual claim is about _Islam_, rather than "the deity of the Abrahamic religions".

Comment: @F1Krazy It's pretty obvious the adherents to those religions share no unity at all, regardless of technical or historical factoids.

Comment: @IMSoP I personally see that as a category error. Heart disease doesn't kill in the same way as religious militants. If we're to make a comparison, to assess the number's gravity, the obvious analog is "Christian murders". Whatever that means, the definitions need to be equal, with just the subjects changing.

Comment: @fredsbend Sure, that was just the first example that popped into my head to compare the "170 million" against. I wasn't suggesting answers used that figure, just that they found some way to contextualise the number. Other random examples: in total, it's about the population of Bangladesh; but averaged per year, it's ~120k, which is the population of Kiribati. Neither are particularly relevant, but they show how reframing a number changes the impression it gives.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### The number cited is 270 million

I found the relevant passage in book you cited, which reads: "“We will be studying the deaths of 270 million Kafirs over 1400 years in jihad. That’s 60 million Christians, 80 million Hindus, 10 million Buddhists and 120 million Africans of varying religions.” I don't know how 270 million became 170 million.

This itself cites *Mohammed and the Unbelievers*, Bill Warner, CSPI Publishing, 2010, pg. 160. I also have found the relevant passage in this book.

### References are provided, but are a mixture of fabrication and misuse of sources

*Mohammed and the Unbelievers* provides the following references:

1. "Thomas Sowell estimates that 11 million slaves were shipped across the Atlantic and 14 million were sent to the Islamic nations of North Africa and the Middle East."

   - It's probably true that North Africans captured well over a million slaves over 1300 years, but Thomas Sowell is a right-wing cultural commentator, not a scholar of slavery. Sowell cites the actual source: Ralph A. Austen, "The trans-Saharan slave trade: a tentative census." *The Uncommon Market: Essays in the Economic History of the Atlantic Slave Trade* (1979). Another historian has objected to these figures: Joseph Inikori, "Africa in World History: The Export Slave Trade from Africa and the Emergence of the Atlantic Economic Order," in B. A. Ogot, ed., *Africa from the Sixteenth to the Eighteenth Century* (Berkeley, Calif., 1992). Inikori says that 15.4 million slaves were brought to the Americas in the Atlantic slave trade, and only 4 million to North Africa. In any case, these figures do not include deaths, and I only linger here because this is the closest we are going to get to reality.
2. "The renowned missionary David Livingstone estimated that for every slave who reached the plantation five others died by being killed in the raid or died on the forced march from illness and privation. So, for 25 million slaves delivered to the market, we have the death of about 120 million people. Islam ran the wholesale slave trade in Africa."

   - Here you can see the first clear factual errors. Warner has added Sowell's two figures together, but the "11 million slaves shipped across the Atlantic" were brought by Christians, not Muslims. This already reduces his estimate by half.
   - I think to back up his thesis that the Atlantic slave trade -- which often involved selling Muslims to Christians -- was an act of jihad, a citation is provided for the claim that "Islam ran the wholesale slave trade in Africa": a book about slavery in the Middle East by Bernard Lewis, the Orientalist. No page number is given. This is a misuse of the source, because Lewis' book says nothing about the Atlantic slave trade.
   - Needless to say, David Livingstone ("Dr. Livingstone, I presume?") was a 19th century colonialist and not a scholar of slavery either. I don't even think he was speaking above his station here, he was just making a general observation that Warner has interpreted as a technical figure. Considering the mention of the "plantation," I also wonder what type of slave raid Livingstone was specifically discussing.
3. "The number of Christians martyred by Islam is 9 million [citation to "World Christian Trends AD 30-AD 2200"]. A rough estimate by Raphael Moore in *History of Asia Minor* is that another 50 million died in wars by jihad."

   - Two citations which are both less and more creative than the previous claims. The first is a citation to a table in a book of Christian demographics, which also shows oddly precise stats like "31,689,000" Christians being killed by atheists, but does not provide any breakdowns for any of its figures. The second is a citation which @AlabamaScholiast pointed out is not a book and is not entitled *History of Asia Minor*, but is actually a [religious essay](https://web.archive.org/web/20040824042410/http://www.serfes.org:80/orthodox/memoryof.htm) entitled "In Memory Of The 50 Million Victims Of The Orthodox Christian Holocaust" by Father Raphael Moore. This article makes only minimal mention of Islam; the "50 million" estimate is a guess at the number of *all* Orthodox Christians killed in the 20th century, including 3.65 million people killed by Turkish ethnonationalists (hence the "Asia Minor" subhead), but *mostly behind the Iron Curtain*, including the Holodomor as a mass extermination. This article does provide a specific number of Orthodox Christians killed by Islamists in Egypt: "dozens." The effects of Islamic extremism on Egypt's Orthodox population should not be understated, but this is not the same as a general holy war by all Muslims on all Christians, and "dozens" is quite different from 50 million.
4. "Koenard [sic] Elst in *Negationism in India* gives an estimate of 80 million Hindus killed in the total jihad against India."

   - I have already dealt with this claim in [another Skeptics answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/did-indias-population-decrease-by-80-million-between-1000-and-1525-ce). There is no evidence given whatsoever for the figure of 80 million -- it's largely based on another nonexistent quotation.
5. "Buddhists do not keep up with the history of war. ... Jihad killed the Buddhists in Turkey, Afghanistan, along the Silk Route, and in India. The total is roughly 10 million."

   - The first sentence is not only false but idiotic; historically, Buddhists engaged in wars of aggression in Myanmar, Sri Lanka, Tibet, etc. and recorded it in their chronicles. The sole citation again goes to "World Christian Trends AD 30-AD 2200". Again, this book doesn't say where exactly it gets its figures.

### Conclusion

We can see an interesting kind of legitimization occurring in the path this "170/270 million" figure took from the fabrications of a self-published lunatic fringe book, to *Crisis* magazine, to Stack Exchange itself.

Comment: *and a citation to a book which, as far as I can tell, does not exist, by a "Raphael Moore" who I do not think exists either. History of Asia Minor ...* -- I think I know a likely candidate for the source. I suspect this comes from [Rev. Fr. Raphael Moore, "In Memory Of The 50 Million Victims Of The Orthodox Christian Holocaust"](https://web.archive.org/web/20040824042410/http://www.serfes.org:80/orthodox/memoryof.htm). First section, which might be mistaken (by an incompetent reader) for title of article, is "History Of Asia Minor: 1894-1923."

Comment: If so, it's not a good source to start with, but this is also a very bad misrepresentation of the contents of the source by Bill Warner, either because he never read it, or because he read it very very badly. [Lots of details in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133379/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-have-about-170-million-peopl)

Comment: Thank you, this explains why I didn't find it on Google Books or Google Scholar. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. FWIW, I think that either Warner (if he read the article) or (if not) his intermediate source is probably reckoning the killing of Christians in 19th/20th century communal violence in the Ottoman Empire & Republic of Turkey (Balkan Wars, Armenian genocide, Greco-Turkish War, etc.) as people killed "in wars by jihad." If so, Moore's estimate for that within the article come out to 3.65 million people killed. Which is rather a highball estimate for those conflicts, but not wildly out of the ballpark for the multidecade long, multi-conflict period Moore is discussing.

Comment: I don't know if that's really the correct way to categorize it, but even if not, seems like a different sort of problem than careless conflation with mass death in Ukraine under Soviet Communism, etc. Really, since the article starts with a long discussion of the Ottoman/post-Ottoman stuff, I suspect the most likely thing to have happened with this source is just that Warner/his intermediate source *stopped reading* at some point in the long first section, and just kind of figured the rest of the 50 million would get filled out somehow or another by basically similar stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how large the number really is, and how it would compare to people killed in the name of another god, or the same god with a different name?

Comment: @EricDuminil no, the reason being because the types of murders which this number *attempted* to cover shows how ambiguous that idea is. Were African slave raids religious inspired? Who authorized them? To capture slaves for US plantations, did Christianity and Islam conspire? Trying to create such a calculation simply sorely misreads human history in favor of one's biases

Comment: @EricDuminil All Abrahamic religions worship the same god, and the names Allah/JHWH/God refer to the same deity.

Comment: @Gantendo yes, and? That's why I wrote it this way. "people killed in the name of Allah" would not refer to people killed by christians, would it?

Comment: @EricDuminil It would, if those Christians killed their victims in the name of God.

Comment: @Gantendo I think you're taking the expression literally, while it's meant figuratively.